# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory with pre-trained model

Tags: image, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am using a pre-trained model for image improvement.

[https://github.com/swz30/MIRNet.][1]

I created a demo.py (code below) file in order to test my set of images for the pre-trained template provided. With my first set of images, all of them with very high resolutions I always got the same error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 5.38 GiB (GPU 0; 3.95 GiB total capacity; 379.90 MiB already allocated; 2.89 GiB free; 16.10 MiB cached)
```

When I tested for only one image with a lower resolution, the error persisted but in a strange way:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1014.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.95 GiB total capacity; 2.61 GiB already allocated; 527.44 MiB free; 23.25 MiB cached)
```

I made the necessary changes to the demo.py file present in the other repository in order to test MIRNet on my image set. During the process I had to make some configurations related to graphics compatibility, but everything was resolved.

Do you have any suggestions to solve my problem? I am using the pre-trained model provided, in a linux environment, with all the correct specifications with anaconda and graphics -> NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960m 4gb

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from PIL import Image
import os
from runpy import run_path
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
from collections import OrderedDict
from natsort import natsorted
from glob import glob
import cv2
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Demo MIRNet')
parser.add_argument('--input_dir', default='./samples/', type=str, help='Input images')
parser.add_argument('--result_dir', default='./samples/output/', type=str, help='Directory for results')
parser.add_argument('--task', required=True, type=str, help='Task to run',
                    choices=['fivek', 'Denoising', 'SR_x3'])

args = parser.parse_args()


def save_img(filepath, img):
    cv2.imwrite(filepath, cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))


def load_checkpoint(model, weights):
    checkpoint = torch.load(weights)
    try:
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["state_dict"])
    except:
        state_dict = checkpoint["state_dict"]
        new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
        for k, v in state_dict.items():
            name = k[7:]  # remove `module.`
            new_state_dict[name] = v
        model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)


task = args.task
inp_dir = args.input_dir
out_dir = args.result_dir

os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)

files = natsorted(glob(os.path.join(inp_dir, '*.jpg'))
                  + glob(os.path.join(inp_dir, '*.JPG'))
                  + glob(os.path.join(inp_dir, '*.png'))
                  + glob(os.path.join(inp_dir, '*.PNG')))

if len(files) == 0:
    raise Exception(f"No files found at {inp_dir}")

# Load corresponding model architecture and weights
load_file = run_path(os.path.join("networks", "MIRNet_model.py"))
model = load_file['MIRNet']()
model.cuda()

weights = os.path.join("pretrained_models/denoising", "model_" + task.lower() + ".pth")
load_checkpoint(model, weights)
model.eval()

img_multiple_of = 8

for file_ in files:
    img = Image.open(file_).convert('RGB')
    input_ = TF.to_tensor(img).unsqueeze(0).cuda()

    # Pad the input if not_multiple_of 8
    h, w = input_.shape[2], input_.shape[3]
    H, W = ((h + img_multiple_of) // img_multiple_of) * img_multiple_of, (
                (w + img_multiple_of) // img_multiple_of) * img_multiple_of
    padh = H - h if h % img_multiple_of != 0 else 0
    padw = W - w if w % img_multiple_of != 0 else 0
    input_ = F.pad(input_, (0, padw, 0, padh), 'reflect')

    with torch.no_grad():
        restored = model(input_)
    restored = restored[0]
    restored = torch.clamp(restored, 0, 1)

    # Unpad the output
    restored = restored[:, :, :h, :w]

    restored = restored.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).cpu().detach().numpy()
    restored = img_as_ubyte(restored[0])

    f = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file_)[-1])[0]
    save_img((os.path.join(out_dir, f + '.png')), restored)

print(f"Files saved at {out_dir}")

  [1]: https://github.com/swz30/MIRNet.
```

Comment: You can test it on Colab which will give you a 11 or 12 GB GPU (usually) so you can get an idea of how much GPU memory is required. You can also try using `torch.cuda.empty_cache` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound dumb, but try to execute this command in terminal:

```
pkill -9 python
```

be careful tho, this command kills all python processes.
Maybe one of this process got stuck while you were trying your code, occupying GPU memory. If this command doesn't solve your problem, try to run the code on Google Colab just to see if the problem persists: Colab should offer you gpus with 10-12Gb of RAM.
Keep us updated